# Integration tests in Gradle using Maven's naming conventions?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, integration-testing

Coming from Maven, I'm exploring Gradle as an alternative. Technologies: Java 11, jUnit 5, Maven 3.6, Gradle 5.6.

I'm stuck in configuring the integration tests. Following the default naming conventions of Maven's Surefire and Failsafe plugins, my tests live in the standard test directory and are distinguished by their suffix: unit tests end in `Test.java` and integration tests end in `IT.java`.

Is it possible to have the same setup in Gradle? So far I've seen two ways:

- use jUnit5's tags (which means I would have to go and tag every integration test)
- use separate directories for unit and integration tests

Ideally, I'd like to keep my folder structure as-is, because it affects multiple git repositories.

Comment: Basically you need to define a new source set that excludes files ending with `Test.java` and configure the existing source set called `test` to exclude files ending with `IT.java`.

Comment: Configure your `test` task to only `include` classes with the suffix used for unit tests. Then create another `Test` task (e.g. `integrationTest`) which only `include`s classes with the suffix used for integration tests. Multiple source sets are also an option, as pointed out by Lukas.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I think I managed to get it working with source sets, thanks to the feedback of [Lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3950370/lukas-k%c3%b6rfer) and [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw).

Please let me know if this can be improved:

```
// define the dependencies of integrationTest, inherit from the unit test dependencies
configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom(testImplementation)
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(testRuntimeOnly)
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            // exclude integration tests from the default test source set
            exclude "**/*IT.java"
        }
    }

    // new source set for integration tests
    integrationTest {
        // uses the main application code
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        java {
            // the tests are at the same directory (or directories) as the unit tests
            srcDirs = sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs

            // exclude the unit tests from the integration tests source set
            exclude "**/*Test.java"
        }
        resources {
            // same resources directory (or directories) with the unit tests
            srcDirs = sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs
        }
    }
}

// define the task for integration tests
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Runs integration tests."
    group = "verification"
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test

    // I'm using jUnit 5
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

// make the check task depend on the integration tests
check.dependsOn integrationTest
```